# Dynamically creating arrays for multiple datasets

Tags: python

This is a quality of life query that I feel like there is an answer to, but can't find (maybe I'm using the wrong terms)

Essentially, I have multiple sets of large data files that I would like to perform analysis on. This involves reading each of these datafiles and storing them as an array (of variable length).

So far I have been doing

```
import numpy as np

input1 = np.genfromtxt('data1.dat')
input2 = np.genfromtxt('data2.dat')
```

etc. I was wondering if there is a method of dynamically assigning an array to each of these datasets. Since you can read these dynamically with a for loop,

```
for i in xrange(2):

input = np.genfromtxt('data%i.dat'%i)
```

I was hoping to combine the above to create a bunch of arrays; input1, input2, etc. without myself typing out genfromtxt multiple times. Surely there is a method if I had 100 datasets (aptly named data0, data1, etc) to import.

A solution I can think of is maybe creating a function,

```
import numpy as np

def input(a):
    return np.genfromtxt('data%i.dat'%a)
```

But obviously, I would prefer to store this in memory instead of constantly regenerate a list, and would be extremely grateful to know if this is possible in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose to store your arrays in either a `dict` or a `list`:

**Option 1**

Using a `dict`.

```
data = {}
for i in xrange(2):
    data['input{}'.format(i)] = np.genfromtxt('data{}.dat'.format(i))
```

You can access each array by key.

---

**Option 2**

Using a `list`.

```
data = []
for i in xrange(2):
    data.append(np.genfromtxt('data{}.dat'.format(i)))
```

Alternatively, using a list comprehension:

```
data = [np.genfromtxt('data{}.dat'.format(i)) for i in xrange(2)]
```

You can also use a `map`, it returns a list:

```
data = map(lambda x: np.genfromtxt('data{}.dat'.format(x)), xrange(2))
```

Now you can access each array by index.

Comment: I'd suggest 1) not shadowing `input`, and 2) use `str.format` instead of `%` and 3) write as comprehensions?

Comment: @JonClements Accepted on all 3 counts. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I forgot that lists do not need to have equal sized elements inside them. A list comprehension is definitely the way to go. Cheers